# UK Consumer Law - Can issuer of gift card expire card without expiry date on card?

Tags: united-kingdom, consumer-protection

I recently purchased a product from a UK company through Amazon, and inside the delivery packaging they included a 'Gift card'.

The card gave details of an offer for first time customers of credit/free products in return for positive review on Amazon, and so I provided such a review (genuine as it is a great product), and provided proof of the review on the 9th Jan.

The Gift card makes no mention of an expiry date, or limited availability, or any other limit on the offer.

The company (via their website and other communications (customer messages on Amazon), that the 'gift card' offer has now expired.

What are my legal rights ? Can a provider claim that an offer has time expired, even though the card detailing the offer has no details of any expiry conditions.

It sounds 'off' to me, but I am not an expert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they offered you a reward in exchange for a good review and then asked for proof that you did the work, it seems like you have a contract with them. Unless they stated clearly in writing that there was an expiration date, it seems like basic breech of contract.

You have a few options. You could complain to Amazon, who might take action against a company abusing the review system but probably won't enforce the contract. You could use Small Claims Court to recover your financial loss.

Or you could simply remove your positive review and replace it with one noting their deception. You can also review sellers as well as items on Amazon, so you can review their behaviour separate to the item.